# Azure DevOps pipelines - create and then select terraform workspace

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-workspace

I have prepared terraform modules for building some IaC infrastructure on Azure Cloud . Currently I am preparing Azure Pipelines release. I have created all the tasks in my pipeline. I want to use terraform deployment on multiple environments like: dev, test, prod, so I decided to use terraform workspaces. I have prepared in my release pipeline for Dev environment following tasks: `terraform init`, `terraform validate`, `terraform plan`, `terraform apply`. Problem is that I am not sure how can I create terraform workspace and then use terraform workspace. When I am creating azure devops pipelines from classic editor there are tasks for creating terraform workspace and selecting terraform workspace actions but they don't work as expected. I am trying to use pipeline variables to stora terraform workspace name, I am using terraform env variable `TF_WORKSPACE`. Provided by MS Tasks in Azure Devops YAML format looks like below.

terraform workspace new task

```
steps:
- task: charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform-cli.TerraformCLI@0
  displayName: 'terraform workspace'
  inputs:
    command: workspace
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Project-Name/drop/Terraform'
    workspaceSubCommand: new
    skipExistingWorkspace: true
```

terraform workspace select task

```
variables:
  TF_WORKSPACE: 'Development'

steps:

    - task: charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform-cli.TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: 'terraform workspace'
      inputs:
        command: workspace
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Project-Name/drop/Terraform'
        workspaceName: '-TF_WORKSPACE $(TF_WORKSPACE)'
```

Comment: There are two terraform commands related to workspaces. 1. To crate a workspace use `terraform workspace new <name>` 2. To select a workspace use `terraform workspace select <name>`.

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, yes, I know that there are two commands, for terraform workspace creation, but in azure devops pipelines there is no option for prepare task for `terraform workspace new WorkspaceName`

Comment: There's an option: it's called the `script` task. You can run whatever CLI command you want. There's really no need to use these wrapper extensions from the marketplace. They don't get you anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have added in Azure DEvops pipeline additional task "Command Line Script", and removed both tasks for `terraform workspace new`, `terraform workspace select` actions. Finally pipeline works as expected.

Comment: Can you share the code with us? Please..